# Implications of using np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray, stride

I have some questions about how `np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided` differs from just using `np.ndarray` and if the `as_strided` can be intercepted by sub-classes to `np.ndarray`.

Given an array:

```
a = np.arange(10, dtype=np.int8)
```

Is there any difference (effectively) between using `as_strided` and creating the `ndarray` with the appropriate strides directly?

```
np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, (9,2), (1,1))
np.ndarray((9,2), np.int8, buffer=a.data, strides=(1,1))
```

`as_strided` just seems to be more implicit about what it is doing.
Can either function be intercepted by a sub-classes for `np.ndarray`? If `a` in the example above was a custom subclass of `ndarray` will there be some function that gets called before returning the strided view? I know that setting `subok` for `as_strided` will preserve any subclass, but is this actually doing anything else than casting the array?

Comment: `as_strided` is python code which you can study.

Comment: Ok, [this seems to be it](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/38bdff05da0859f45bebf5a0c32869d58365b02f/numpy/lib/stride_tricks.py#L96) and it looks like it does the same as using ```np.ndarray```. I thought at first it would be similar to ```np.reshape``` since both methods are just changing metadata.